# pthread argument's value changed

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

This is my main function, where `NO_RECIEVERS = 3`. I am trying to differentiate between the writer and reader threads using the value of `i` that i send.

```
int main() {
    int status, i;
    pthread_t tr[NO_RECIEVERS], tw[NO_SENDERS], bd;
    i=1;

    for(i=1; i<=NO_SENDERS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tw[i-1], NULL, writer, &i);
    }

    for(i=1; i<=NO_RECIEVERS; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        pthread_create(&tr[i-1], NULL, reader, &i);
    }

    pthread_create(&bd, NULL ,daemon_thread, NULL);

    for(i=1; i<=NO_SENDERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(tw[i-1], NULL);
    }

    for(i=1; i<=NO_RECIEVERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(tr[i-1], NULL);
    }
    pthread_join(bd, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

My reader function is as follows

```
void* reader(void *val) {
    int ret, fd, id;
    struct mssg data;
    id = *(int*)val;
    printf("id: %d %d\n", id, *(int*)val);
    while(1) {
```

But this function seems to be creating threads with id some random values.. i get a log like this

```
...
id: 1 1
...
id: 2 2
...
id: 1 1
```

Next time i get.. its kind of random

```
...
id: 1 1
...
2
id: 2 2
...
id: 4 4
```

But the values i am assigning are limited to 1,2,3

Comment: You don't try to do this in kernel-space, don't you?

Comment: @alk No its just a user program to access the kernel dev file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed `&i` to all the threads you created... so each one has a pointer to `i`, and when they dereference that to read the value of `i`, and what they read is whatever `i` happens to be at the time.

If you want to pass the value of `i` at the time of the `pthread_create`, I suggest `malloc()` a small piece of memory, copy `i` to it and pass the malloced thing to the thread (which can read it and the `free()` the memory.  Or any other method that provides a copy of `i` in a different location for each thread created.

Comment: Seems to be that is the only option... Any way of doing it with local variables, i mean static vars

Comment: If you know exactly how many threads you are going to create, then you could define a static array of `i_for_thread`, with one entry for each thread to be created, set the entry for each thread before creating it, passing the address of that entry to the thread.

Comment: @Lonewolf: As you seem to be knowing the number of threads in advance just define `int is[NO_RECIEVERS]` and initialise it in the loop by doing `is[i]=i;` and pass `&is[i]` to `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Since `i` is just an `int` you can pass `(void*) i` and in the thread function cast it back: `id = (int) val;`.  If you're concerned about losing information in the casts, then use `intptr_t` instead of `int` for `i` and `val`, since `intptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to cast to and back out of a `void*` without loss.