# Thread pool - handle a case when there are more tasks than threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm just entered multithreaded programming and as part of an exercise trying to implement a simple thread pool using pthreads.

I have tried to use conditional variable to signal working threads that there are jobs waiting within the queue. But for a reason I can't figure out the mechanism is not working.

Bellow are the relevant code snippets:

---

```
typedef struct thread_pool_task
{
    void (*computeFunc)(void *);
    void *param;
} ThreadPoolTask;

typedef enum thread_pool_state
{
    RUNNING = 0,
    SOFT_SHUTDOWN = 1,
    HARD_SHUTDOWN = 2
} ThreadPoolState;

typedef struct thread_pool
{
    ThreadPoolState poolState;
    unsigned int poolSize;
    unsigned int queueSize;
    OSQueue* poolQueue;
    pthread_t* threads;
    pthread_mutex_t q_mtx;
    pthread_cond_t q_cnd;
} ThreadPool;
```

---

```
static void* threadPoolThread(void* threadPool){

    ThreadPool* pool = (ThreadPool*)(threadPool);
    for(;;) 
    {
        /* Lock must be taken to wait on conditional variable */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(pool->q_mtx));

        /* Wait on condition variable, check for spurious wakeups.
           When returning from pthread_cond_wait(), we own the lock. */
        while( (pool->queueSize == 0) && (pool->poolState == RUNNING) ) 
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&(pool->q_cnd), &(pool->q_mtx));
        }

        printf("Queue size: %d\n", pool->queueSize);

        /* --- */
        if (pool->poolState != RUNNING){
            break;
        }

        /* Grab our task */
        ThreadPoolTask* task = osDequeue(pool->poolQueue);
        pool->queueSize--;


        /* Unlock */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->q_mtx));

        /* Get to work */
        (*(task->computeFunc))(task->param);
        free(task);
    }


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->q_mtx));
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return(NULL);
}
```

---

```
ThreadPool* tpCreate(int numOfThreads)
{
    ThreadPool* threadPool = malloc(sizeof(ThreadPool));
    if(threadPool == NULL) return NULL;


    /* Initialize */
    threadPool->poolState = RUNNING;
    threadPool->poolSize = numOfThreads;
    threadPool->queueSize = 0;

    /* Allocate OSQueue and threads */
    threadPool->poolQueue = osCreateQueue();
    if (threadPool->poolQueue == NULL)
    {

    }
    threadPool->threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numOfThreads);
    if (threadPool->threads == NULL)
    {

    }

    /* Initialize mutex and conditional variable */
    pthread_mutex_init(&(threadPool->q_mtx), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(threadPool->q_cnd), NULL);

    /* Start worker threads */
    for(int i = 0; i < threadPool->poolSize; i++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&(threadPool->threads[i]), NULL, threadPoolThread, threadPool);
    }

    return threadPool;
}
```

---

```
int tpInsertTask(ThreadPool* threadPool, void (*computeFunc) (void *), void* param)
{
    if(threadPool == NULL || computeFunc == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Check state and create ThreadPoolTask */
    if (threadPool->poolState != RUNNING) return -1;
    ThreadPoolTask* newTask = malloc(sizeof(ThreadPoolTask));
    if (newTask == NULL) return -1;
    newTask->computeFunc = computeFunc;
    newTask->param = param;

    /* Add task to queue */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadPool->q_mtx));
    osEnqueue(threadPool->poolQueue, newTask);
    threadPool->queueSize++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&(threadPool->q_cnd));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadPool->q_mtx);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The problem is that when I create a pool with 1 thread and add a lot of jobs to it, it does not executes all the jobs.

[EDIT:]
I have tried running the following code to test basic functionality:

```
void hello (void* a)
{
   int i = *((int*)a);
   printf("hello: %d\n", i);
}
void test_thread_pool_sanity()
{
   int i;

   ThreadPool* tp = tpCreate(1);

   for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
   {
      tpInsertTask(tp,hello,(void*)(&i));
   }
}
```

I expected to have input in like the following:

```
hello: 0
hello: 1
hello: 2
hello: 3
hello: 4
hello: 5
hello: 6
hello: 7
hello: 8
hello: 9
```

Instead, sometime i get the following output:

```
Queue size: 9 //printf added for debugging within threadPoolThread
hello: 9
Queue size: 9 //printf added for debugging within threadPoolThread
hello: 0
```

And sometimes I don't get any output at all.
What is the thing I'm missing?

Comment: You have posted too much code. You need to provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least describe clearly what problem you are facing than this: *I have tried to use conditional variable to signal working threads that there are jobs waiting within the queue. But for a reason I can't figure out the mechanism is not working.*

Comment: The problem is when I create a pool with 1 thread and add a lot of jobs to it, it does not executes all the jobs.

Comment: Can you say what you expect? What exactly is wrong? E.g. when you compile and execute, what output is desired for which input?

Comment: I will edit the question in a minute.

Comment: There is a problem with your test program. You are passing the `param` argument to `tpInsertTask` as `&i`, which is a pointer to the local variable. That means (i) it will have exactly the same value for all threads, (ii) the value of `i` will likely get overwritten before a thread picks up the task and reads it, and (iii) `i` will go out of scope before the `hello` function dereferences it, leading to undefined behaviour. You probably want to either use a cast (`(void *)i`) or allocate an `int` to store the value of `i` in, like you're doing for the task itself.

Comment: Your "basic functionality test" erroneously [passes a pointer to an automatically allocated and changing loop variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25964643/132382), which is not what you want.  It also suggests there may be coding errors in your program which you've not revealed.  As @BlueMoon said, please provide an MVCE.

Comment: How are you shutting down the thread pool at the end of your test process?

Comment: Indeed it is exactly the root of the problem.
Trying to figure out now, how to properly shut down the pool.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `tpInsertTask(tp,hello,(void*)(&i));` you are passing the address of i which is on the stack. There are multiple problems with this:

1. Every thread is getting the same address. I am guessing the hello function takes that address and prints out *param which all point to the same location on the stack.
2. Since i is on the stack once test_thread_pool_sanity returns the last value is lost and will be overwritten by other code so the value is undefined.

Depending on then the worker thread works through the tasks versus when your main test thread schedules the tasks you will get different results.

You need the parameter passed to be saved as part of the task in order to guarantee it is unique per task.

EDIT: You should also check the return code of pthread_create to see if it is failing.

Comment: I edited my hello function to fix the problem you mentioned.
However the results are still not what I expect.

Comment: The problem is not in the hello function but how you pass the parameter to the hello function. One option would be to allocate memory to hold the int, store i into the pointer, pass that pointer as the parameter, and have the hello function free it.